# Compilation Error FileNotFound

Tags: java

Whenever I am compiling the code it is showing this error. It is a simple java code to copy a file. I have saved the text file in `src` and in workspace both. I tried in both ways by giving directory of txt file but i am getting the same error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   src\input.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at CopyFile.main(CopyFile.java:15)
> ```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyFile {

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try
    {
        in = new FileInputStream(" src/input.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("src/output.txt");

        int c;
        while ((c=in.read()) != -1)

        {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally
    {
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
        }
        else if (out != null)
        {
            out.close();
        }
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: put your file in `resources` folder. To retrieve the resource: `getClass().getResource("input.txt")`

Comment: well little space do make a difference `in = new FileInputStream(" src/input.txt");` remove the space from the path.

Answer (score 2):

The space in:

```
    in = new FileInputStream(" src/input.txt");
```

is probably messing up your path, even if the file really is in `src/input.txt`. Delete the space, and check to make sure that the file is actually where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a compilation error, it is a runtime error.

You should double-check the working directory in which the application executes (since `src/input.txt` is a *relative path*). Oftentimes, using Eclipse or other IDEs it is not what you might expect (i.e. relative to project source, or binaries, ...) but it can be configured in the project settings.